# Python3.8 asyncio Streams and read

Tags: python, sockets, stream, python-asyncio

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm missing something that I think is probably obvious:

I'm working with the Python 3.8 asyncio streams:

```
import asyncio

async def client_handler():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 9128)

    server_name = writer.get_extra_info('peername')[0]
    print(f"Connecting to: { server_name }")
    data = b''
    close_client = False
    try:
        while not close_client:
            print(data)
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            print(data)
            if data != b'':
                print(data.decode('utf-8'))
                data = b''
        writer.close()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(client_handler())
```

I guess I expected that it would try to read 1024 bytes but if there was nothing there, then it would just return None or an empty byte string or something, but instead it just sits there until data is received.

Am I misunderstanding what read is supposed to do?  Is there instead another method that I could use to peek into a buffer or poll to see if any data is actually incoming?

For instance, lets say I'm writing an example chat program server and client that need to be able to dynamically send and receive data at the same time... how do I implement that with the asyncio streams?  Should I just build my own asyncio.Protocol subclass instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools like `asyncio.gather()`, `asyncio.wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)`, and `asyncio.wait_for()` to multiplex between different operations, such as reads from different streams, or reads and writes. Without additional details regarding your use case it's hard to give you concrete advice how to proceed.

Building an `asyncio.Protocol` or using `feed_eof()` directly is almost certainly the wrong approach, unless you are writing very specialized software and know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: for a client, i would expect to just have both read and write only to a single server, not from multiple servers / streams

Comment: @DavidTorrey So, what else do you need? Why is it a problem for you that `await stream.read(n)` actually waits for new data?

Comment: shouldn't i need the same loop to be able to write out as well?  if it's getting locked up just trying to read, how would I be able to, for send out data?  am I misunderstanding this?  Like lets say as a client i want to be able to randomly type in a terminal and have it write out to the server while it's waiting to read data.

Comment: or what if, for isntance, i'm waiting for data to come from a server, but I want to be able to send something back to the server while i'm waiting for more data to come in... maybe a button click, or an interrupt, etc...

Comment: @DavidTorrey Then you'd have two coroutines running in parallel, one charged with reading from the terminal and transmitting it to the network, the other reading from network and displaying data to the client. Asyncio would run both on the same thread and the same event loop, turning them into async code. That's what I referred to by "using tools like `asyncio.gather()` in the answer.

Comment: got it, i think i understand now.  asyncio is very new to me, that's kind of what i was thinking lastnight as i was looking through it but wasn't sure.  appreciate the help

Comment: @DavidTorrey *or what if, for isntance, i'm waiting for data to come from a server, but I want to be able to send something back to the server while i'm waiting for more data to come in* - no problem, you'd just throw in a coroutine that handles that with the appropriate `asyncio.sleep()`, `asyncio.wait_for()`, etc.

Comment: just to follow up quick if you don't mind, i'd do something like this then: await asyncio.gather(read_data(reader),write_data(writer)) correct?  and handle a read loop then do what i want for write?

Comment: @DavidTorrey In asyncio streams `write` is not a coroutine, so you don't need `gather` for reading and writing in parallel. But you may need `gather()` (or `asyncio.create_task()`, etc.) for other stuff that should be done in parallel, depending on what you actually need to do.

Comment: you don't need to await on a write() but you need to `drain()` it at some point. Also you ask what is wrong with async-blocking on read(), the answer is simple: it prevents flow control that is otherwise possible: cancelling the future and closing the connection (for some reason).

Comment: @Eric Your comment sounds like it's addressed to the asker. If that is the case, you probably want to post it under the question instead of here, so they get notified.

Comment: I'm not sure to whom that remark was directed, but some people reading may find it useful nonetheless.